Why is my digitally signed PDF invalid in Adobe Acrobat despite correct configuration?
I’m working on a project where I need to digitally sign a PDF using Node.js. My goal is to sign the PDF with a .pfx certificate and include a timestamp (TSA). However, despite following the expected process, Adobe Acrobat reports that the signature is invalid. The certificate itself is valid, and the signed file passes validation on the ITI verifier (Brazilian official digital signature verifier), but not in Acrobat.
What I’ve Done:
1.  Used the @signpdf/signpdf library for signing.
2.  Added a ByteRange placeholder with @signpdf/placeholder-plain.
3.  Configured the TSA using the URL: https://freetsa.org/tsr.
4.  Ensured the .pfx certificate matches the private key.

const fs = require('fs');
const { plainAddPlaceholder } = require('@signpdf/placeholder-plain');
const { SignPdf } = require('@signpdf/signpdf');
const { P12Signer } = require('@signpdf/signer-p12');

// Paths
const pdfPath = '../resources/pdf-entrada.pdf'; // Input PDF
const pfxPath = '../resources/certificado.pfx'; // PFX certificate
const signedPath = '../resources/output-signed.pdf'; // Final signed PDF
const pfxPassword = 'your_password_here'; // Certificate password
const tsaUrl = 'https://freetsa.org/tsr'; // TSA URL

async function signPdfWithTSA() {
  try {
    console.log('--- Start of Signing Process ---');
    console.log('[1] Reading the original PDF...');
    const pdfBuffer = fs.readFileSync(pdfPath);
    console.log(`[1] Original PDF size: ${pdfBuffer.length} bytes`);

    console.log('[2] Adding ByteRange (Placeholder for signature)...');
    const pdfWithPlaceholder = plainAddPlaceholder({
      pdfBuffer,
      reason: 'Digital Signature',
      contactInfo: 'email@example.com',
      name: 'Your Name',
      location: 'City / Country',
    });
    console.log(`[2] PDF with Placeholder size: ${pdfWithPlaceholder.length} bytes`);

    console.log('[3] Reading the PFX certificate...');
    const pfxBuffer = fs.readFileSync(pfxPath);
    console.log(`[3] PFX certificate size: ${pfxBuffer.length} bytes`);

    console.log('[4] Configuring signer with TSA...');
    const signer = new P12Signer(pfxBuffer, { passphrase: pfxPassword, tsaUrl });
    const signPdf = new SignPdf();

    console.log('[5] Signing the PDF...');
    const signedPdfBuffer = await signPdf.sign(pdfWithPlaceholder, signer);
    console.log(`[5] Signed PDF size: ${signedPdfBuffer.length} bytes`);

    console.log('[6] Saving the signed PDF...');
    fs.writeFileSync(signedPath, signedPdfBuffer);
    console.log(`[6] Signed PDF saved at: ${signedPath}`);
    console.log('--- End of Signing Process ---');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error while signing the PDF:', error.message || error);
  }
}

signPdfWithTSA();

My console output:
--- Start of Signing Process ---
[1] Reading the original PDF...
[1] Original PDF size: 22368 bytes
[2] Adding ByteRange (Placeholder for signature)...
[2] PDF with Placeholder size: 39989 bytes
[3] Reading the PFX certificate...
[3] PFX certificate size: 9200 bytes
[4] Configuring signer with TSA...
[5] Signing the PDF...
[5] Signed PDF size: 39989 bytes
[6] Saving the signed PDF...
[6] Signed PDF saved at: ../resources/output-signed.pdf
--- End of Signing Process ---

Problem:

Adobe Acrobat shows the signature as invalid.
It states that the document was signed using the local time of the computer, despite configuring the TSA.
The signed file passes the ITI verifier, but not Acrobat.

Link to signed PDF

Can you share an example signed PDF for analysis?

I edited the question and added the link to the PDF at the end.

Thank you!
I have uploaded and replaced the link.

Adobe Acrobat shows the signature as invalid.
In short, your signer certificate has a certificate policy OID that explicitly is not accepted by Acrobat. You need a different type of certificate.
In detail, let's take a look at what Adobe says exactly:

So cryptographically the signature is ok ("has not been modified") and the issue is that Acrobat does not accept your certificate ("Signer's certificate is invalid"). Thus, the signature validity problem is not related to your code.
Why does Acrobat consider your certificate invalid? Let's take a look at the certificate in the Acrobat certificate viewer:

As you can see at the bottom, Acrobat sees invalid policy constraints in your certificate. This refers to the Certificate Policies value I've selected on the Details tab on the right side: Your certificate has been created with the certificate policy with OID 2.16.76.1.2.1.133.
But take a look at the Policies tab of the entry for the root "Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5" certificate:

Here you can see that there are Policy value restrictions for the signer certificate. Unfortunately one cannot scroll the allowed Certificate Policies field, but looking into Acrobat's data files one finds the accepted OID ranges:

2.16.76.1.2.3.1 - 2.16.76.1.2.3.138
2.16.76.1.2.4.1 - 2.16.76.1.2.4.58

As you see, only values from the 2.16.76.1.2.3.* and the 2.16.76.1.2.4.* OID branch are accepted while your certificate has a policy from the 2.16.76.1.2.1.* branch.
In other words, certificates like yours explicitly are excluded from trust by Acrobat. If you want your signature to be accepted by other users' Acrobat instances, you'll have to switch to a certificate Acrobat does trust.
It states that the document was signed using the local time of the computer, despite configuring the TSA.
Analyzing the embedded signature container, there indeed is no embedded timestamp token. Thus, for some reason your code does not embed it. As I don't know the used signing API, I cannot suggest further measures.
The signed file passes the ITI verifier, but not Acrobat.
Different validators may apply different validation routines to signatures. In particular the range of acceptable signer certificates - defined by trust anchors and additional restrictions - may differ.
As explained above, Acrobat only accepts signer certificates issued by "Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5" if they contain certain certificate policy OID entries. ITI may allow other OID ranges, too, or may ignore the policy OID altogether.

Related thread on community.adobe.com: https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/pdf-sign/m-p/13905653#M418011
